# knowledge article url in community

Tags: community, knowledge, url

In a community I want to access to a knowledge article by a link. I have something like this :

```
href="{!'/c/article/' + currentFile.urlName}"
```

with `currentFile.urlName` that is the `KnowledgeArticleVersion.UrlName`.

Concretely, the url look like this :

> https://my-org-salesforce.cs88.force.com/c/article/test-lightning

But when I click it I got the error

> URL No Longer Exists

Comment: what is url is printing when you click on the url?

Comment: "URL No Longer Exists"  as I said in my question... I got this error message, and the URL is the one I wrote in the question. Maybe the url in the code is wrong, if so what should I put ?

Comment: Which community template you are using?

Comment: I use the napili template

Comment: url should be in a format like https://my-org-salesforce.cs88.force.com/articles/[articleType]/[URLName]

Comment: what is [articleType] ?

Comment: That is what you first create before you creating articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Napili URL should be:

https://my-org-salesforce.cs88.force.com/s/article/test-lightning

You can verify that it from community builder.

It's constructed as: `<Community base URL>+'/s/'+'/article/'+<articleURLname>`

[image]